# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException locating an element using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to crawl a page that loads certain data using js request using selenium so I used "visibility_of_element_located" with a timeout. however, even setting it for 15 seconds
doesn't work and I get a timeout error.

```
url = '''https://ukranews.com/en/news/850009-u-s-believes-russia-s-war-with-ukraine- 
will-last-until-end-of-2022-cnn'''        
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.page_load_strategy = "none"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                           executable_path='C:\\Users\\313-SsS\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe',
                           )
browser.get(url)
timeout_in_seconds = 5
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout_in_seconds).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'article_content')))
browser.execute_script("window.stop();")
html = browser.page_source
```

Here is the error I got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x008E7413+2389011]
```

I also use the same code for another website that also loads the content using js and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are atleast ***8*** elements which is identified by the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout_in_seconds).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'article_content')))
```

[image: 8 elements]

---

### Solution

To wait for the visibility of the *`<h1>`* element with text as ***U.S. Believes Russia's War With Ukraine Will Last Until End Of 2022 - CNN*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.article_content h1")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='article_content']//h1")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: still have the same problem. after 20 seconds I got selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException error.

Comment: Remove `--headless` and retest and let me know what you see.

Comment: it works now. Thanks a lot. but how can I stop it from opening the browser now?

Comment: @mohsenamini Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.